# Runtime Exception- feature not implemented yet

Tags: java, runtimeexception

The following block of code showing this error "Runtime Exception- feature not implemented yet" in jelliot, when it reaches the line

```
char arr [] = w.toCharArray();
```

And in other compilers,it won't take the number of input it's supposed to take. If I set n=4, it only takes 2 inputs.

```
    Scanner Sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    int n = Sc.nextInt();
    for(int count = 1;count<=n; count++){
        String w = Sc.nextLine();
        char arr [] = w.toCharArray();
        if(arr.length > 4){
            System.out.print(arr[0]);
            System.out.print(arr.length-2);
            System.out.print(arr[arr.length-1]);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println(w);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: `If I set n=4, it only takes 2 inputs.`  seems like it will take 3 and which java version you are using , doesn't support `CharArray` ?

Comment: Can you explain what "jeliot" is (and which version you are using) ? Looks like it is some library/ application that does not support fully what you are trying to do.

Comment: it is set as count<=n, not count<n. So it supposed to take 4. @PavneetSingh

Comment: "Jeliot 3 is a Program Visualization application. It visualizes how a Java program is interpreted. Method calls, variables, operation are displayed on a screen as the animation goes on, allowing the student to follow step by step the execution of a program. Programs can be created from scratch or they can be modifyed from previously stored code examples. The Java program being animated does not need any kind of additional calls, all the visualization is automatically generated. Jeliot 3 understands most of the Java constructs and it is able to animate them" i am using version 3 @StefanFreitag

Comment: first you said it is taking `2 input` and second try this in your else statement `w+"you pressed enter"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception indicates that this particular method (`toCharArray()`) of the `String` class isn't implemented for the (presumably non-standard) implementation of java that you're using. You can work around this by not using a char array, and instead using the `String` methods `length()` and `charAt()`. Try this:

```
Scanner Sc = new Scanner (System.in);
int n = Sc.nextInt();
for(int count = 1;count<=n; count++){
    String w = Sc.nextLine();
    if(w.length() > 4){
        System.out.print(w.charAt(0));
        System.out.print(w.length()-2);
        System.out.print(w.chatAt(w.length()-1));
    }
    else{
        System.out.println(w);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```